# Shower Drain Pipe Outer Ring

Tags: shower, drain

[image]Updated photo to show make and model - I'm no plumbing expert but it appears that this black raised/bubbled ring around the shower drain pipe needs attention. It's gotten worse over time. Shower drain cover doesn't fit properly anymore. Is it a rubber gasket with silicone of some sort that was used? I'm afraid to scrape it off/out. The shower was put in about 6 years ago. Could I use Flexiseal in case it chips away too much? I almost chipped it away to clean it but figured I better leave it alone until I find out what it is.[image]

Comment: What's the make/model of that item? Your photo cuts off that part of the inscription.

Comment: all it needs is some proper cleaning

Comment: Adding to @Ruskes - it looks like it could be an O-ring.  Unless it's frayed, cracked or broken, its probably ok.

Comment: Do you have access to whatever's below this? If so, can you check there for signs of leaking?

Comment: No signs of leaking underneath.